# MVC model compliance

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller

I have an app that writes a lot of data to a CoreData DB which I will interrogate and give feedback based on user queries.

For now I have the DB actions in my VC and would like to move this to a separate file which I called modelDB.

```
// MARK: Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var courseField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var par3Field: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var par4Field: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var par5Field: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var errorLabel: UILabel!

// MARK: Actions
@IBAction func addNewCourse(sender: AnyObject) {

  let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

  let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

  let newCourse = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("CourseDB", inManagedObjectContext: context)

  newCourse.setValue(courseField.text, forKey: "courseName"
  newCourse.setValue(Int(par3Field.text!), forKey: "totalPar3")
  newCourse.setValue(Int(par4Field.text!), forKey: "totalPar4")
  newCourse.setValue(Int(par5Field.text!), forKey: "totalPar5")

  do {

    try context.save()
    performSegueWithIdentifier("Back", sender: self)

  } catch {

    errorLabel.text = "Data was not saved"

  }

}
```

From the above you can see that I'm writing data to the DB which I rather want to do in the modelDB file and then pass it back to the VC.

Can you please give me some pointers on how to achieve this?

NEW INFORMATION & HELP NEEDED
I created a global array to capture and pass the information contained in the UITextFields:

```
newCourseList = [courseField.text!, par3Field.text!, par4Field.text!, par5Field.text!]
modelDB.addNewCourseToDB(newCourseList)
```

When running this I get a fatal error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value", although the array has the 4 values.

The func where I pass to, inside ModelDB class, looks like this:

```
    func addNewCourseToDB(_: [String]) {

                let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

                let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

   // code
    }
```

but the code does not reach this stage because of the error.
How do I fix this passing of array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to communicate with the `ModelDB` class (assuming it is a class), just add a property to the view controller.  This is a good way to establish the relationship:

```
var modelDB: ModelDB!
```

Regarding managing communication from `ModelDB` back to the controller, there are number of ways to do this, all described very will in this objc.io issue:

https://www.objc.io/issues/7-foundation/communication-patterns/